# Django MySQL with ElasticSearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I have a django app.

Data is stored in mysql database. There are many tables with many columns (100-200).

How can I use Elasticsearch to make search faster?

Do I need to rewrite all queries?

Links to tutorials will be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, no time for a full answer, but try looking into Haystack, http://haystacksearch.org/, for a start.

Answer (score 1):

Django Haystack is a popular library for integrating search into Django projects.

You can check out their "Getting Started Guide" here: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.1/tutorial.html

Edit:

You probably won't be able to find something that is a plug & play solution and doesn't require you to touch any code. However integrating Haystack for a basic use-case doesn't require very much work.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.